# Change Detection on Input Array

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I am inputting an array of objects into a component that are generated from an HTTP request response (asynchronous), and I want to fill up a different array with just the first three array elements.

I want to fill up the new array at the same time as the first array gets assigned from the parent input.

Here's my code that does not work:

```
private _images: any[];
private threeImages: any[];

@Input() 
set images(images: any[]) {
    this._images = images;
    for(let i=0; i < 3; i++){
        this.threeImages = images[i];
    }
}
get images() { return this._images }
```

Why can't I intercept input property changes of an inputed array using a setter? And what is a good alternative way to achieve the outcome I want?

Comment: Can you show us how this is called in the parent component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working, see my plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZIjepnYZ5IS8FfktU0C1?p=preview

You need to push those `images[i]`'s to the array instead of assign it every time.

```
import {Component, NgModule, Input} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-cmp',
  template: `my-cmp!`,
})
export class MyCmp {

  private _images: any[];
  private _threeImages: any[];

  @Input() set images(images: any[]) {
    this._images = images;

    this._threeImages = []; // CLEAR IT !
    for(let i=0; i < 3; i++) {
      this._threeImages.push(images[i]);
    }

    console.log(this._images);
    console.log(this._threeImages);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
    <my-cmp [images]="myImages"></my-cmp>
  `,
})
export class App {

  private myImages: any[] = [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, MyCmp ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Dangit. My mistake. Thanks!